Tracking schedule dates that can occur once annually
I have a strange situation that I need to resolve for a project I am planning in MS Project 2021.
The schedule dates have multiple dependencies due to leaseholds, including cancellation dates and actual leasehold end dates as a result.
Is there a way to automate the setting/selection of dates for this as other items are adjusted? Missing a date pushes the project by an entire year, so quite important to track it properly.
Tasks

Purchase land


Dependent on prior tasks


Cancel leasehold


Task 1 must be completed
Issue: Can occur once per year prior to March 16th


Leasehold is cancelled


Task 2 must be completed
Issue: Occurs 1 year after Task 2 was completed, on March 16th the following year


Development of land


Task 3 must be completed

I know that I can set predecessors for tasks, but how do I lock things to next occurrance of March 16th?
Thanks in advance!

Create a custom calendar with March 16th as the only active day. Use that calendar as the Task Calendar for a one day (or one minute) task that is driven by the predecessor tasks and has the follow-on tasks as the successor. Note, the one working day task cannot be a milestone.
Creating the single day every year requires multiple exceptions.

From now until Mar 15 of next year (non-working)
From Mar 17, 2025 until Mar 15, 2026 (non-working)
And so forth

If the predecessor tasks attempt to push past the March 16 date, they will automatically be reset to next year's March 16 date.

Worked like a charm! Thank you for such an "easy" solution to a complex legal situation. :)
I'll award the bounty to you as soon as the timer runs out on the ability to do so in about 8 hours.

Martin, you're welcome and thanks for the feedback.
